# How to parse a key - value based dictionary using Perl

Tags: dictionary, perl, hashmap

Using Perl I get a `key` - `value` based dictionary from an API call.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;
my $url = "http://example.com/?id=124341";
my $content = get($url);
$content =~ s/ /%20/g;
print $content;


{"id":"85710","name":"jack","friends":["james","sam","Michael","charlie"]}
```

How can I parse it  to get the results as below?

```
name : jack
hist friend list :
james
sam
Michael
charlie
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON 'decode_json';

my $content = '{"id":"85710","name":"jack","friends":["james","sam","Michael","charlie"]}';

my $person = decode_json($content);
print "name : $person->{'name'}\n";
print "his friend list :\n";
for my $friend ( @{ $person->{'friends'} } ) {
    print "$friend\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
use JSON; # imports encode_json, decode_json, to_json and from_json.


my $href  = decode_json($content);

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $href;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
use JSON::Tiny 'j';

my $data = j $content;

printf <<TEMPLATE, $data->{name}, join( "\n", @{ $data->{friends} } );
name : %s
his friend list:
%s
TEMPLATE
```