# How can I assign a variable's content to a variable's name in perl?

Tags: perl, variables, assign

For example

```
$get = <>;
chomp($get);
$$get = "something";
```

if user inputted name for $get
I want to assign "something" to $name

Comment: What you are looking for is a dictionary (called a "hash" in Perl). See [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923585/how-to-parse-a-key-value-based-dictionary-using-perl)

Comment: http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "hash" (or "dictionary" in some other languages) is like* an array of key-value pairs. This achieves what you describe because you can assign a value to a variable without having a fixed identifier for that variable.

*: Hashes are *not* arrays.

See [this tutorial on Perl101](http://perl101.org/hashes.html). The following code snippets in this answer are taken from this site.

You can create a hash using the following syntax:

```
my %stooges = (
    'Moe', 'Howard',
    'Larry', 'Fine',
    'Curly', 'Howard',
    'Iggy', 'Pop',
);
```

Access and modify *values* using `{}`. You can use this syntax to *add new values* too.

```
print $stooges{'Iggy'}; #get existing
$stooges{'Iggy'} = 'Ignatowski'; #Overwrite
$stooges{'Shemp'} = 'Howard'; #Set new
```

You can delete key-value pairs using the `delete` function.

```
delete $stooges{'Curly'};
```

You can get a list of values or keys using the same (key)words:

```
my @stooge_first_names = keys %stooges;
my @stooge_last_names = values %stooges;
```

Comment: It would be more common to write your hash as a 'fat comma' delimiter of `=>`. Means the same thing, but makes the key-value pairings clearer.

Comment: Well, I was hoping visitors would click the link, as the fat comma style is mentioned there. I wasn't aware it was more common though,

Comment: *"Hashes are not arrays"* why mention arrays in the first place?

Comment: @Borodin should I edit to say "list"? That's also a data type in some languages. Or perhaps "group"

Comment: @Arc676: Hmm. It's difficult to think in the mindset where hashes are alien! I personally *hate* the term "associative array" precisely for this reason, and because a standard array "associates" an index with a value so it's really no use at all. In the end I think the idea of a "map" or a "table" represents the idea best, And you can reference [Wikipedia's *hash table*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) entry to do the heavy lifting

Answer (score 6):

There are ways to do this, but you really shouldn't. Use a hash instead.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $get = <>;
chomp $get;
my %input;
$input{$get} = "something";
```